# Read/write kivy widget attributes with python

Tags: python, widget, kivy, textinput

I have a basic, working knowledge of Python I'm trying to teach myself kivy.  I'd like to be able to have Python read and write data to kivy widgets.

Imagine there's an address book app that inserts the date and time into a TextInput.  When the app starts, just have Python get the date and time and insert it right?

This program code will give an example of a simple address book:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class AddressApp(App):
    def build(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
AddressApp().run()
```

Here's its address.kv file:

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 2
    Label:
    text: 'Date'
TextInput:
    id: textinputdate
Label:
    text: 'Time'
TextInput:
    id: textinputtime
Label:
    text: 'Name'
TextInput:
    id: textinputname
Label:
    text: 'Address'
TextInput:
    id: textinputaddress
Label:
    text: 'email'
TextInput:
    id: textinputemail
Label:
    text: 'Phone'
TextInput:
    id: textinputphone
```

After that, if I wanted to have Python read the... I dunno... uh... phone number TextInput, how would that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A guy named spinningD20 on the FreeNode IRC channel for kivy showed me this.

There's an even easier way than adding a custom widget.  As long as you just want to insert a value into the TextInput when the app starts up...

address.py

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

import time

class AddressApp(App):
        def build(self):
            self.root.ids.textinputdate.text = time.strftime("%x")

if __name__ == '__main__':
        AddressApp().run()
```

address.kv

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 2
    Label:
        text: 'Date'
    TextInput:
        id: textinputdate
    Label:
        text: 'Time'
    TextInput:
        id: textinputtime
    Label:
        text: 'Name'
    TextInput:
        id: textinputname
    Label:
        text: 'Address'
    TextInput:
        id: textinputaddress
    Label:
        text: 'email'
    TextInput:
        id: textinputemail
    Label:
        text: 'Phone'
    TextInput:
        id: textinputphone
```

Comment: Putting any code inside `build` method, which isn't about an app general behavior, is strongly discouraged. Sometimes you want to re-use widgets in other apps, and this solution makes it impossible without unnecessary further rewrites. In other words, such things should be embedded inside custom widgets to save yourself work in future.

Comment: It depends on the situation.  

In this case, I'm putting a default value into a TextInput.  In other words, I'm going through application set-up.  I don't need to create a library of custom TextInputs and if I do I end up creating half a dozen of them making more work for myself than if I just insert values into them at startup.

Comment: Then populate them in a parent widget, in this case a grid layout. It's just a good practice.

Comment: Would you give an example of that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want some widget to have an extra functionality (example: loading current date at app start), then create a custom version of that widget, which meets requirements. And reading values of widgets within a rule is very simple. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.clock import Clock
import time

gui = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2

        Label:
            text: 'current time'

        DateInput:
            id: date_input

    Button:
        text: 'write date to console'
        on_press: print(date_input.text)
'''


class DateInput(TextInput):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DateInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)  # update every second

    def update(self, dt):
        self.text = time.ctime()


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(gui)


Test().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

spinningD20 here.  To be fair, I answered his immediate question, but also followed it up with an explanation of encapsulating it into a custom widget:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

import time


class DateInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DateInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = time.strftime("%x")


class Container(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # using super calls the base class's init.  We'll hand it keyword arguments we received, just in case
        super(Container, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # now we can do stuff here
        self.ids.textinputtime.text = 'from python'


class AddressApp(App):
        def build(self):
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
        AddressApp().run()
```

and in kv:

```
# anything without the <> symbols is part of the App's kv.  So here's the one thing the App will have in its kv
Container:

# here's the custom widget's kv, just like your previous example
<Container>:
    cols: 2
    Label:
        text: 'Date'
    DateInput:
        id: dateinputdate
    Label:
        text: 'Time'
    TextInput:
        id: textinputtime
    Label:
        text: 'Name'
    TextInput:
        id: textinputname
    Label:
        text: 'Address'
    TextInput:
        id: textinputaddress
    Label:
        text: 'email'
    TextInput:
        id: textinputemail
    Label:
        text: 'Phone'
    TextInput:
        id: textinputphone
```

I hope this helped!  Good luck Dave!

Answer (score 0):

Another example, explaining how to populate text inputs with current date through a parent grid layout, avoiding App class to keep it clean:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import time

gui = '''
#:import time time
DateGrid
    cols: 1

    Label:
        text: 'Customer data'

    TextInput:
        id: date_input

    TextInput:
        id: name_input

    TextInput:
        id: email_input

    Button:
        text: 'refresh date'
        on_press: date_input.text = time.ctime()
'''


class DateGrid(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DateGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.populate_inputs, 0.5)

    def populate_inputs(self, *x):
        _ = self.ids

        _.date_input.text = time.ctime()
        _.name_input.text = 'Foo Snowman'
        _.email_input.text = 'foo.snowman@gravy.com'


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(gui)


Test().run()
```